# How to check if the key has list of objects as values and then iterate through the children and display them

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to display the json response which has key value pairs and some of the keys have objects which I want to iterate and display in the dom .

I have tried and got the values displayed for the keys which have got direct values like AcctiveFlag, DateofBirth.

```
>Json response :
>ActiveFlag: -1
>Address: [{…}]
>BadAddressDate: null
>ContactID: 9999
>ContactName: "William Clem Dec"
>DateOfBirth: "1972-08-17T00:00:00"
>Phone: [{…}]
>PrimaryFirstName: "William"
>PrimaryLastName: "Clem Dec"
>PrimaryMiddleInitial: null
>RoleCode: 0
>RoleCodeDescription: null
>TaxID: "338722304"
>TaxIDType: "SSN"
>Udfs: {}
```

But I want to iterate through phone ,address and display their key and value too . 
Below is my code [This the view in the dom right now how the values are being displayed in a modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsiBB.png)

```
var contactPromise = http.get(contactUrl).then(function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var c = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (key in data[i]) {
            var e = document.createElement("div");
            e.className = "col-lg-3";
            e.innerHTML = "<div class=\"input-group\"> <span class=\"input-group-addon\" id=\"key\">" + key + "</span> <input id=\"accountModelId\" type=\"text\" disabled class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Account Model\" aria-describedby=\"accountModel\" value=" + data[i][key] + "></div>";
            $searchModal.find('#contactData').append(e);
        }
    }
    $searchModal.modal('show');
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: what's $searchModal ? why are you mixing jquery and js when you can achieve everything with js?

Comment: For IE9+ there is Array.isArray() function which will determine if an object is an array, so that you can decide if you want to iterate  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: this application is based on nodejs . var $searchModal = $($.parseHTML(require("../fnSearch/resources/fnSearchModal.html"))) . this is the import of the modal where we append the html .

Comment: yes, as @daddygames said check if the key in data is an array type, if its an array then do the appending inside the if block. right now you are not checking if its an array.

Comment: yes@Hith  you are right  I am not checking it currently  and yeah I would try what daddygames has suggested. Thanks  (Y)